# What is the expression for splitting?

Tags: excel

I  have to split this query in Excel without using any macro functions.
The values below in this format can be dynamic:

```
value to be split-> a:10;b:20;c:30
```

I  want output of this above value like this separately in each cell in Excel like this:

```
 a 10
 b 20
 c 30
```

Comment: Yes, you can split the words, just Refer the [Link][1]. It will help you.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/483419/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-in-ms-excel

Comment: Reposted [on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/982356/how-do-i-split-this-query-in-excel-without-using-any-macro-functions).

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To get the parsed data to appear in a *column* rather than a *row*, pick some cell and enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,";",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

then copy **down**:

[image]

Comment: I want a:10 within two cells also

Comment: like a in cell A and 10 in cell B

Comment: @JatinKhanna You could use a **similar** formula to parse the cells using the ***:*** character.

Comment: can you please write full code. do not want to use two formulae